# Ammonia complex

Tags: coordination-compounds

I am desperately trying to find an aqueous chemical that will selectively form a complex with ammonia gas. Any suggestions please?

I am building a gas sensor for ammonia

Comment: Why use a complex in the first place? Is litmus paper not good enough?

Comment: Five seconds on google give this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925400504008196

Comment: also: Cu2+, but how do you make a sensor out of this info?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Drager tube for ammonia, this is a porous pad with the acid form of a pH indicator and a known amount of acid in each unit length of the pad. You could base your sensor on a pH sensor combined with an electrochemical cell which generates acid.

If you can devise electronics which can maintain a constant voltage from a glass electrode (combined with a reference electrode) by adjusting the flow of current through a cell which generates acid at one electrode. The other electrode would need to be behind a membrane.

Another apporuch would be to use cobalt or another transition metal. The formation of ammonia complexes will alter the redox properties of an electrode. If you had copper electode exposed to the air with a thin layer of liquid on it, which is one electode and the other electode is a reference electode isolated by a salt bridge or membrane from the copper electrode then you could see a change in cell emf as a function of the amount of ammonia which the cell is being (or has been exposed) to.